# Drag and Drop into columns

Tags: jquery

I'm developing an `E-Learning Web Application`.

In my site I want to add a Drag And Drop, where I have a section which contains a list of items, those items can be dragged and dropped into three sections, which will contain those items.

This is an example of what I want to do :

[image]

You can check it in this website :

http://learning.aljazeera.net/dailytraining/pages/5d57b40f-5fac-4db2-96bb-dfb6bec3cb01?Level=1

I googled about some jQuery plugin which do the same, but I couldn't find anything helpful, all I find is the sortable drag and drop, and upload drag and drop.

If someone could help me with some jQuery plugin, I'll be greatful.

Comment: did you try http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Jquery-ui plugin called [Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists)!